# Перевод JS файлов

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

Подскажите пожалуйста как выполнить перевод строк на другой язык в **JS** файлах в приложений **Laravel 7-8**?

Пример кода:

```
$(".cancel").on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr("href");
    
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, Do It!'
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value == true) {
            window.location.href = link;
        }
    })
});
```

Пробивал стандартными **{{ __('Are you sure?') }}** - **__('Are you sure?')** методами постоянные ошибки. Подскажите пожалуйста еще один способ.

Comment: у вас ларавел эти js файлы генерит,или что?

Comment: @teran Привет! Нет они уже созданные. Не изменяются и не генерируются. Обычный статический файл.

Comment: если у вас это отдельный js вне php, то надо в него i18n подключать и уже рулить переводами внутри. Но возможно в lavarel есть что-то встроенное на эту тему.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev Привет. Пробежался по папке vendor вроде нет что-то похожего. Подскажи пожалуйста как подключить i18n к проекту? Ввел в строку поиска i18n на сайте https://packagist.org/ там много результатов.

Comment: не смогу подсказать как в проект lavarel подключить, со стороны фронта надо настраивать сборку всего этого. сам i18n js тут лежит, но простого применения без сборки не вижу. https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev Спасибо за помощь.